# file_put_contents is not overwrite / overwrite context option not specified

Tags: script, ftp, php

I heard that file_put_contents overwrite the file if it exist ? That's what i want but it doesn't work. What do?

```
  $contentsAnnonces = file_get_contents("http://website1.fr/file.xml");
  $filename = "http://website2.fr/file.xml";
  file_put_contents($filename, $contentsAnnonces);
```

Error :

**Remote file already exists and overwrite context option not specified**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot write to HTTP using `file_put_contents()`.

From the [`file_put_contents()` documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php):

> A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the [fopen
>   wrappers](https://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) have been enabled. See [fopen()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) for more details on
>   how to specify the filename. See the [Supported Protocols and
>   Wrappers](https://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php) for links to information about what abilities the various
>   wrappers have, notes on their usage, and information on any predefined
>   variables they may provide.

And from [PHP's description of the HTTP protocol](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php) (emphasis mine):

> Allows ***read-only access*** to files/resources via HTTP 1.0, using the HTTP GET method.

`file_put_contents()` writes to a file, but it cannot do so over HTTP because the wrapper can only read HTTP using GET.

---

You need a different approach to accomplish what you want.

From the document root of `website2.fr`, you can write a script that writes to `file.xml` after fetching the file from `http://website1.fr/file.xml`.

Example:

```
<?php
$contentsAnnonces = file_get_contents("http://website1.fr/file.xml");
file_put_contents(ORIGINE_DU_DOCUMENT . "/file.xml", $contentsAnnonces);
```

… where `ORIGINE_DU_DOCUMENT` is the path to the document root on the site `website2.fr`.

When you run the script, the contents of `http://website2.fr/file.xml` would be identical to the contents of `http://website1.fr/file.xml` as retrieved over HTTP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if i do understand i write the same code as mine but i execute the script on website2 so i will not have to put a url but just the path of the directory where i want put the file contents ?

Comment: That is correct, @imoopsy.